# destinos entre fragments con navcontroller

Tags: fragment, navigation, jetpack-compose

Estoy intentado hacer la navegación entre fragmentos a través de un recyclerview donde traigo información y lo que pretendo hacer es que cuando se le de clic a un imageview me lleve a otro fragment para reproducir un video pero me estoy encontrando con el siguiente error que no se como puedo solucionar:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.mundomedicos.fitapp.navigationcomponent, PID: 15242
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Navigation action/destination com.mundomedicos.fitapp.navigationcomponent:id/action_rutenFragment_to_videosrutinaFragment cannot be found from the current destination Destination(com.mundomedicos.fitapp.navigationcomponent:id/rutinas) label=Rutina de entrenamiento class=com.mundomedicos.fitapp.navigationcomponent.fragmentosUsuario.RutinaFragment
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.kt:1216)
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.kt:1149)
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.kt:1575)
        at com.mundomedicos.fitapp.navigationcomponent.fragmentosUsuario.RutenFragment.onReproducirClick(RutenFragment.kt:74)
        at com.mundomedicos.fitapp.navigationcomponent.adaptadores.MovieAdapter$ViewHolder.bind$lambda-3(MovieAdapter.kt:53)
        at com.mundomedicos.fitapp.navigationcomponent.adaptadores.MovieAdapter$ViewHolder.$r8$lambda$aQyUh58BE_KTlic3lDNEGzdFfFM(Unknown Source:0)
        at com.mundomedicos.fitapp.navigationcomponent.adaptadores.MovieAdapter$ViewHolder$$ExternalSyntheticLambda5.onClick(Unknown Source:4)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7125)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7102)
        at android.view.View.access$3500(View.java:801)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27336)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

comparto parte de mi código para ver si alguien entiende donde me pueda estar equivocando y así ofrecer una posible solución

nav_graph.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:id="@+id/nav_graph"
            app:startDestination="@id/inicio">
        
            <fragment
                android:id="@+id/rutinas"
                android:name="com.mundomedicos.fitapp.navigationcomponent.fragmentosUsuario.RutinaFragment"
                android:label="Rutina de entrenamiento"
                tools:layout="@layout/fragment_rutina" >
                <action
                    android:id="@+id/action_rutinaent_to_entrenamiento"
                    app:destination="@id/entrenamiento" />
            </fragment>
            <fragment
                android:id="@+id/entrenamiento"
                android:name="com.mundomedicos.fitapp.navigationcomponent.fragmentosUsuario.RutenFragment"
                android:label="@string/entreno"
                tools:layout="@layout/fragment_index" >
                <action
                    android:id="@+id/action_rutenFragment_to_videosrutinaFragment"
                    app:destination="@id/videosrutinaFragment" />
                <action
                    android:id="@+id/action_entrenamiento_to_seriesFragment"
                    app:destination="@id/seriesFragment" />
                <action
                    android:id="@+id/action_entrenamiento_to_diasFragment"
                    app:destination="@id/diasFragment" />
            </fragment>
            <fragment
                android:id="@+id/videosrutinaFragment"
android:name="com.mundomedicos.fitapp.navigationcomponent.fragmentosUsuario.VideosrutinaFragment"
                android:label="@string/reproductor"
                tools:layout="@layout/fragment_videosrutina" >
                <argument
                    android:name="viden"
                    app:argType="com.mundomedicos.fitapp.navigationcomponent.modelos.Rutinadia" />
            </fragment>
        </navigation>
```

Comment: Hola, al parecer quieres ir de `id/rutinas` a `id/videosrutinaFragment`, pero la acción está en `id/entrenamiento`, por eso no encuentra la acción para navegar. Básicamente tienes que estar parado en `id/entrenamiento` o modificar la ruta de la acción.

Comment: ese es el inconveniente que me tomando rutinas como ruta de inicio cuando el inicio es entrenamiento y su destino es videosrutinas y no se como hacer para ubicar mi inicio en el fragment entrenamiento. Ya elimine la dirección que había de rutinas a entrenamiento y reconstruí el proyecto pero sigue saliendo el error.

Comment: Una forma de evitar que salga el error es validar en qué fragment estás por medio de `if(findNavController().currentDestination?.id==R.id.entrenamiento){ //ejecutar accion de navegacion }` de esta manera aseguras de que la acción se ejecute desde el fragment correcto, esto puede suceder porque la acción de ejecuta varias veces mientras se esta haciendo la transición, de igual forma debes controlar que las invocaciones de la acción no sean llamadas múltiples veces

Comment: @AbrahamChan muchas gracias por indicarme como llevar el control de la navegación. Excelente aporte.

Answer (score 0):

Una forma de evitar que salga el error es validar en qué fragment estás de la siguiente forma:

```
if(findNavController().currentDestination?.id==R.id.entrenamiento){ 
    //ejecutar accion de navegación 
}
```

De esta manera aseguras de que la acción se ejecute desde el fragment correcto.

Esto puede suceder porque la acción se ejecuta varias veces mientras ocurre la transición. De igual forma debes controlar que las invocaciones de la acción no sean llamadas múltiples veces.

Comment: Lo pongo como respuesta por si otras personas se topan con el mismo detalle.

Comment: grande!!!. me ayudo demasiado.